# how to create external table from csv file with commas in quote field in greenplum?

Tags: linux, greenplum

I'm trying to create external table from csv like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hctest.ex_nkp
(
a text,
b text,
c text,
d text,
e text,
f text,
g text,
h text
)
LOCATION ('gpfdist://192.168.56.111:10000/performnkp.csv')
FORMAT 'CSV' (DELIMITER ',' HEADER);
```

The csv is delimited by comma (,) and looks like this :

```
"Subject Username","Form Title","Form Start Date","Form End Date","Competency Name","Competency Description","Core Competency","Competency Official Rating"
"90008765","Performance Review - 2nd Semester 2019 for Ely Eisley","01/01/2019","31/12/2019","1. Uncompromising Integrity","<p>High ethical standards, low tolerance of unethical conduct.</p>","Yes","3"
"90008766","Performance Review - 2nd Semester 2019 for Ely Eisley","01/01/2019","31/12/2019","2. Team Synergy","<p>Passionately work together, ensuring completeness, to achieve common goals.</p>","Yes","3"
"90008767","Performance Review - 2nd Semester 2019 for Ely Eisley","01/01/2019","31/12/2019","3. Simplicity","<p>We do our utmost to deliver the easy to use solutions, exceeding customers&#39","","
"90008768","Performance Review - 2nd Semester 2019 for Ely Eisley","01/01/2019","31/12/2019","4. Exceptional Performance","<p>Highest level of performance, with a heart for people.</p>","Yes","3"
```

And i found the error:

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column  (seg0 slice1 192.168.56.111:6000 pid=14121)
DETAIL:  External table ex_nkp, line 5 of file gpfdist://192.168.56.111:10000/performnkp.csv
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your CSV is malformed in line 4. Notice that at the end of line 4, there is a single quote, and Greenplum is interpreting that as a CSV field with a line break. By adding the missing quote on line 4, I am able to read the file in Greenplum.

```
"Subject Username","Form Title","Form Start Date","Form End Date","Competency Name","Competency Description","Core Competency","Competency Official Rating"
"90008765","Performance Review - 2nd Semester 2019 for Ely Eisley","01/01/2019","31/12/2019","1. Uncompromising Integrity","<p>High ethical standards, low tolerance of unethical conduct.</p>","Yes","3"
"90008766","Performance Review - 2nd Semester 2019 for Ely Eisley","01/01/2019","31/12/2019","2. Team Synergy","<p>Passionately work together, ensuring completeness, to achieve common goals.</p>","Yes","3"
"90008767","Performance Review - 2nd Semester 2019 for Ely Eisley","01/01/2019","31/12/2019","3. Simplicity","<p>We do our utmost to deliver the easy to use solutions, exceeding customers&#39","","
"90008768","Performance Review - 2nd Semester 2019 for Ely Eisley","01/01/2019","31/12/2019","4. Exceptional Performance","<p>Highest level of performance, with a heart for people.</p>","Yes","3"
```

Resulting query:

```
fguerrero=# select * from ex_nkp ;
NOTICE:  HEADER means that each one of the data files has a header row
    a     |                           b                           |     c      |     d      |              e              |                                         f                                          |  g  | h
----------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+---
 90008765 | Performance Review - 2nd Semester 2019 for Ely Eisley | 01/01/2019 | 31/12/2019 | 1. Uncompromising Integrity | <p>High ethical standards, low tolerance of unethical conduct.</p>                 | Yes | 3
 90008766 | Performance Review - 2nd Semester 2019 for Ely Eisley | 01/01/2019 | 31/12/2019 | 2. Team Synergy             | <p>Passionately work together, ensuring completeness, to achieve common goals.</p> | Yes | 3
 90008767 | Performance Review - 2nd Semester 2019 for Ely Eisley | 01/01/2019 | 31/12/2019 | 3. Simplicity               | <p>We do our utmost to deliver the easy to use solutions, exceeding customers&#39  |     |
 90008768 | Performance Review - 2nd Semester 2019 for Ely Eisley | 01/01/2019 | 31/12/2019 | 4. Exceptional Performance  | <p>Highest level of performance, with a heart for people.</p>                      | Yes | 3
(4 rows)
```

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can specify "LOG ERRORS SEGMENT REJECT LIMIT 10" in your external table definition. This way, segment will skip the rows with errors. 
Then you can come back to trace the detail with "select * from gp_read_error_log('external_table_name');" 
From the example, it looks like you have extra comma in the field. Try to specify QUOTE '"' after HEADER.